# Embbed html/javascript in org-mode html export

Tags: org-mode, html, javascript

Is it possible to embed an html file within an html exported from org-mode?

I don't mean to "quote" the source of the file (which is possible with `#+INCLUDE: "someFile.html" src html`).

My use case is: I have a standalone html containing a simple D3 visualization. I'd love to link somehow to this html within org-mode so that once I export the org file, the visualization would dispay in the output html.

My current workarounds:

1. simple linking to the standalone html `[[file:...]]` so the visualization opens when user clicks on it.
2. Alternative is is to manually copy the code into the output html from org-mode - but this is highly impractical.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#+INCLUDE: "someFile.html" html` should result in an included rendered version of the html file and not just "quote the source file".

Comment: This is correct! I was trying #+INCLUDE: "someFile.html" src html. Without "src" it embeds. Amazing! BTW: there is a colon ":" after INCLUDE.

Comment: Sorry - one more question: after export org-mode replaces the INCLUDE with a html source block. Is it possible to prevent this? The target html might change and I'd like org-mode always fetch the actual version at the time of export. Is this possible?

Comment: @user673592: thanks for hinting the missing colon! I've fixed that mistake. To your question: I don't actually see the behavior that the include statement in the org file is replaced with the source code. I'm using `org-html-export-to-html` for my testing and after exporting, the include statement is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

In my current org version 9.0.10, the right command is

```
#+INCLUDE: "someFile.html" export html
```

with the word `export`.